# What's wrong with the Basic configuration of apache and mod_python?

Tags: apache-http-server, python, django

the the Basic configuration of apache is:

```
LoadModule python_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_python.so
<Location "/mysite/">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
        PythonOption django.root /mysite
        PythonDebug On
        PythonPath "['/var/www/html', '/usr/local/gdnsplus_conf/www/mysite'] + sys.path"
</Location>
```

I have done:

```
ln -sf /usr/local/gdnsplus_conf/www/mysite /var/www/html/gdnsplus_conf
```

the version of django is:1.4.5 
the version of mod_python is:3.3.1 
the directory of of django app is:  /usr/local/gdnsplus_conf/www/mysite 
the context of app is:

```
ll /usr/local/gdnsplus_conf/www/mysite
total 184
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root  2970 Mar 25 16:20 conf.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root  4992 Apr 25 17:15 cv
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root  4991 Apr 25 17:16 cv_all
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root  6727 Mar 29 18:05 hand_xml.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root     0 Mar 12 09:12 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root   134 Mar 12 09:15 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root  5720 Apr 17 15:27 settings.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root  5400 Mar 12 09:33 settings.py.bk
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root  3118 Apr 17 15:27 settings.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root  2080 Apr 22 13:34 tags
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache root  4096 May  9 13:46 templates
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root    62 Apr 27 11:05 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root  1238 May  9 11:09 urls.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root  1144 May  9 11:10 urls.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root 34352 May  9 13:45 views.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root 30384 Apr 16 09:06 views.py.bk
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root 33425 May  9 14:55 views.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root  1134 Mar 12 09:12 wsgi.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache root  1028 Mar 12 09:15 wsgi.pyc
```

the infomation of  urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^conf_xml/$', receive),
        (r'^dc_list/$', listall),
        (r'^show_err/$', show_err),
        (r'^ipdb_file/$', ipdb_file),
        (r'^ipdb_update/$', ipdb_update),
        (r'^task_list/$', task_list),
        (r'^task_search/$', task_search),
        (r'^nip_set/$', nip_set),
        (r'^nip_del/$', nip_del),
        (r'^nip_update/$', nip_update),
        (r'^ns_set/$', ns_set),
        (r'^ns_list/$', ns_list),
        (r'^reversion_list/$', list_version),
        (r'^version_set/$', version_set),
        (r'^index/$', all_err),
        (r'^machine/$', show_machine),
```

The question is:

```
http://192.168.23.73/ns_list/
```

is not work.The wrong message is "File does not exist" from apache log.

How to solve it ? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you are requesting is not within your Django application. Only URLs prefixed with /mysite will be routed to your Django application. Thus, would need to be:

```
http://192.168.23.73/mysite/ns_list/
```

BTW, you do know that mod_python is no longer developed or maintained and you would be better off using a different hosting mechanism for Django?